# Joining 3 tables in SQL/PHP

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join 3 tables tags, itemtags and transactions. 
Transactions is a list of payments. Itemtags links the transactionid (from "transactions") to the tagid that corresponds with the correct tag details in 'Tags'.

I want to link all three tables so that I can see both the "tagname" field within "Tags" and "Billdate" in Transactions. My code isn't working - when I try and do the mysql_fetch_array I get the following error:

"Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean"

Any help gratefully received!

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT
tags.tagid,tags.tagname,
itemtags.tagid,itemtags.transactionid 
transaction.transactionid,transaction.billdate
FROM 
tags 
  LEFT JOIN itemtags ON tags.tagid = itemtags.tagid
  LEFT JOIN transaction ON itemtags.transactionid = transaction.transactionid
WHERE
DATE(`transaction.billdate`) >= '$startdate' AND 
DATE(`transaction.billdate`) <= '$enddate'
");

while($val=mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
print ' '.$val['tagid'].' - '.$val['tagname'].' ||';
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Are you setting your result variable to $result = [backtick]mysql_query(...)[backtick], and using that $result in your mysql_fetch_array($result)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query definitely has errors in it, to debug the errors being caused, use the code below.

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will result in printing out the correct error that the sql query is throwing, I'll gladly help you with the query once you tell me what the exact error is :)

The corrected query, or closer to being correct, should look like the following. Please note, I've adjusted your date comparisons, as the DATE() syntax wasn't necessary :)

```
SELECT
    tags.tagid,
    tags.tagname,
    itemtags.tagid,
    itemtags.transactionid,
    transaction.transactionid,
    transaction.billdate
FROM tags 
  LEFT JOIN itemtags ON tags.tagid = itemtags.tagid
  LEFT JOIN transaction ON itemtags.transactionid = transaction.transactionid
WHERE
transaction.billdate >= '$startdate' AND 
transaction.billdate <= '$enddate'
```

Comment: It says: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.transactionid,transaction.billdate FROM tags LEFT JOIN itemtags ON tags.tag' at line 4

Comment: Try out the new query, and let me know :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Please "accept" my answer if it truly helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your first left join, and you can use alias's to get the same column twice

```
mysql_query("SELECT
tags.tagid,tags.tagname,
itemtags.tagid,itemtags.transactionid as itemtagstransid, 
transaction.transactionid as transtransid,transaction.billdate
FROM 
tags 
  LEFT JOIN itemtags ON tags.tagid = itemtags.tagid
  LEFT JOIN transaction ON itemtags.transactionid = transaction.transactionid
WHERE
DATE(`transaction.billdate`) >= '$startdate' AND 
DATE(`transaction.billdate`) <= '$enddate'
");`
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I've corrected those errors - as above, but it's still coming up with the same error? I'll play with the alias's once it works to work out how to use them!